# How to make a mobile menu that is dynamic in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, css, react-native

I want to make a menu that I press on an item, I change to that item that has other subitems and so on. However, I do not know how to do it. I leave the code that I tried:

https://codesandbox.io/s/n9598q6xy0?fontsize=14

I want for example, the following menu. Now, I click on **"Item 1".**

[image: Sample image]

It takes me to **"Item 1"** with its contents:

[image: Sample image]

And I also press on the **"subitem 1"** or I press on the arrow of **">"** and it takes me to the content of **"subitem 1".**

[image: Sample image]

Finally, how would the **"<"** menu backlash between menus be?

I am very grateful, I have tried and I have not succeeded. Thanks!

Comment: What you need is a combination of `setState` which renders your menu with a certain class name that triggers a css transition.

Comment: Would it have to change state but hidden the previous one or how?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe I'm missing something here to understand exactly what you want

Comment: I tried to make an onclick and change to an image for example, and it does. However, when it comes to so many subitems within items I do not know how to put them. Are they put in view as hidden or how?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Yes, in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/n9598q6xy0?fontsize=14